# AngularJS how to set variable in $http success function of dependency provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm newbie in angularjs and I'm trying to create new provider. This is my code:

```
myApp.provider('$Data', function() {
    this.URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore, SG, Singapore, 153 Bukit Batok Street 1&sensor=true';

    this.$get = $get;
    $get.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

    function $get($http, $q) {
        var that = this;
        return {
            isConnected: function() {
                var bIsConnected = 'Default';
                $http({method: 'GET', url:that.URL}).then(function (data) {
                           bIsConnected = 'Yes';
                           alert('Run this code!');
                        }, function (data) {
                            bIsConnected = 'No';
                        });
                return bIsConnected;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/0udm9/9dPsb/6/

After I run $Data.isConnected(), the result is always 'Default' although browser show the alert box. I think it's from success function is not of $get. And I have to use provider, not service or factory for this case. Can I do anything to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use promise in your code.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/miraage/zFuQh/1/)

Provider:

```
isConnected: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(that.url).then(function(res) {
        deferred.resolve('Yes');
        console.log('example:success', res);
    }, function(err) {
        deferred.resolve('No');
        console.log('example:error', err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Controller:

```
$Data.isConnected().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

// UPD

You must use objects if you need to use return values with async code.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/miraage/zFuQh/4/)

// UPD 2

[FRESH DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKtscnSjA7Z70OmqWVWE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, Miraage! But it's only simple example. Can we set variable in this function? I have other function named isUser() to check user logged in or not.
Please check the Jsfiddle. 
[http://jsfiddle.net/0udm9/9dPsb/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/0udm9/9dPsb/6/)
Thanks

Comment: You can not assign primitive variable this way. I will give you another example in 5-10 mins.

Comment: @Miraage, could you please update the links for your jsFiddle?

Comment: @medokr, yep, a bit later. I need to do tons of job. Lunch break will be in 1-2 hours.